# Add fade to image transistion

Tags: javascript, image, fadein, fade, fadeout

I have a changing background image that currently uses this script. I am not a javascript expert and would like to add a fade effect as it transitions from one slide to the next. What would I need to add?

```
function changeBgImage (image, id) {
var element = document.getElementById(id);
element.style.backgroundImage = "url("+image+")";
}
```

Thanks as always!

Comment: as I say compete novice what would I need to add in order to make it fade?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to include jquery.js and use element.fadeOut() before changing the background and element.fadeIn() after changing it, something like this:

```
var element = document.getElementById(id);
$('#' + id).fadeOut();
element.style.backgroundImage = "url("+image+")";
$('#' + id).fadeIn();
```

Include jquery in the head of your html document:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ok so I have query included any way and my id to do the change image is main-cony can i just add this script to the one in my original post to fade this changing background if so what should it look like? Sorry if this sounds dumb its just as I say javascript is new to me!

Comment: if your element's id is 'main-cony' then try this in your function: `$('#main-cony').fadeOut();
    $('#main-cony').css('background-image', 'YOUR NEW URL');
    $('#main-cony').fadeIn();`

Comment: hmm not quite. Basically I have a background image on my page. Upon mouse over of different buttons the background image changes to something that relates to where that button will take you. The background image is changing using the script in my original post but it changes instantly which doesn't look right, so I was hoping there was an easy way to add to the above script so that when it carried out the transition it faded rather the just changed. I hope that makes sense!

Comment: I'm sorry, as I see it, this should work .. did you try it? and what did happen?

Comment: It flashed over and over continuously on the page :) however this line confused me .css('background-image', 'YOUR NEW URL'); if its not to cheeky could you add it to my original script to show me how the whole thing should look? as i say the your new URL confused me as there are multiple depending on what you click

Comment: this line would be: `.css('background-image', 'url('+image+')');` in your case..and the image should fade out and fade back in with the new image